# Not able to launch IE/Chrome from Selenium Webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While launching IE from Selenium Webdriver following error is shown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system
>   property.     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService.access$1(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService$Builder.build(InternetExplorerDriverService.java:230)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:263)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:155)

Code used :

```
  public class Browser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver obj = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Eclipse Workspace\\Multi Browser\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    obj.get("http://www.google.com/");
    obj.close();
  }
```

Comment: Check your browser version; is that 25+? Also, your driver should be located properly C://chromedriver.exe

Comment: Yes its 33.xx. So the resolution is in downgrading chrome ? Chromedriver is added in project folder so no problem there.

Comment: Yes try to downgrade and check the same

Comment: But what about the path mention in http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver which says chrome should be in App Data ?

Comment: I would go with @PrashanthSams suggestion, put the driver in an actual folder and reference it **explicitly** in the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property. It's the reason for your error, nothing to do with Chrome's location.

Comment: I've explicitly mentioned path but eclipse is giving is error notification "invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Code Lines(i switched writing for ie same error given in this case) :  
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
WebDriver objWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\Eclipse Workspace\CoE1\IEDriverServer.exe" );

Comment: Use like this ==> System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\Eclipse Workspace\\CoE1\\IEDriverServer.exe" );

Comment: You have to set property first, then instantiate the IE Driver. So the code should be:   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Eclipse Workspace\\Multi Browser\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver obj = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InternetExplorerDriver` object should be created ***after*** the `webdriver.ie.driver` property is set. Similarly for chrome.

Also, the referenced code uses `getProperty()`, whereas you need to use `setProperty()` to actually set it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Eclipse Workspace\\Multi Browser\\IEDriverServer.exe");

WebDriver obj = new InternetExplorerDriver();
obj.get("http://www.google.com/");
obj.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setProperty()` function. Basically, you have to set this property before you initialize driver. But you are using `getProperty()`.

Here is the sample Java code:

```
public class IE {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\SATHISH\\SOFTWARES\\SELENIUM\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("www.google.com");
            driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("abc");
            driver.close();

    }

}
```