# ClassNotFoundException while automationg login to a page using selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to automate login to facebook. I have tried to connect selenium to chrome driver and IE driver. But when i execute the code I get a class not found exception for com.google.common.base.Function. I tried to google it and downloaded the jar file for com.google and added it to eclipse. But then i get an IllegalStatementException on this line

```
WebDriver wd=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Here is the code.

```
package com.automate;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class ConnectToUrl {
    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        WebDriver wd=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        wd.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
        wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Email");
        wd.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        wd.findElement(By.id("u_0_l")).click();
    }
}
```

What is the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: You need download latest iedriverserver.exe and set to system property with IEdriverserver.exe executable from system location path before initiating `InternetExplorerDriver()`

Comment: where i can find this IEdriverserver.exe?

Comment: Go to [this URL](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and download latest. IEdriverServer which is suitable with your OS...:)

Comment: have done it still getting the classnotfounfexception

Comment: You need to build path with appropriate class jar...:)

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\manishk1\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
This is the statement that i wrote

Comment: But you're initialising `InternetExplorerDriver` so you need to set property for `IEDriverServer.exe`

Comment: If you want to use ChromeDriver then try as : `System.setProperty("‌​webdriver.chrome.driv‌​er", "C:\\Users\\manishk1\\D‌​esktop\\Selenium\\chrom‌​edriver.exe");  WebDriver wd= new ChromeDriver();`..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dependency , most likely Google's guava libraries. If you have a maven based project you can include the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As for the illegal statement exception , you should refer this question: [Not able to launch IE/Chrome from Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017678/not-able-to-launch-ie-chrome-from-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: no i am not using maven. So i need to download it explicitly and add it to my project. right?

Comment: That is right , not sure if guava has other internal dependencies though , you will have to add them manually as well. Also , for the second exception , the webdriver.ie.driver should be set first as in the thread. Hope it helps !